# MVC Model not binding to HTTPPost action

Tags: vb.net, post, razor, model-view-controller, controller

Whenever I submit my form from the `Respond.vbhtml` page, my `Respond_post` function inside the controller gets called like it should; however, the item being passed in `FormsRespondModel` is empty.

[image]

Why is my post action not populating my FormsRespondModel as it should?

**FormsRespondModel.vb**

```
Public Class FormsRespondModel
    Public Property form As cihForm
    Public Property lists As cihLists = New cihLists()
    Public Property subOrgs As List(Of cihOrganizationSub)
    Public Property Events As List(Of cihEvent)


    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(formId As String)
        form = New cihForm()
        form.loadForm(Guid.Parse(formId))

        lists.loadOrganizationSubs(ZenCommon.CurrentOrgId, ZenCommon.CurrentUserId)

        Dim emptyList() As String = {}
        Dim eventsearchList As cihEventSearch = New cihEventSearch(ZenCommon.CurrentOrgId, "", DateTime.Now, ZenCommon.Date2050, True, emptyList, emptyList, emptyList)

        Events = eventsearchList.eventList
        subOrgs = lists.organizationSubs

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Respond.vbhtml**

```
@ModelType CheckImHere.Student.FormsRespondModel

@Using Html.BeginForm()
 @html.Hidden(Model.form.formId.ToString())
@For Each fld As Field In Model.form.fields
  If fld.fieldTypeId = "text" Then
   @<li>
      <h4>@fld.title</h4>
      <em>@fld.description</em>
      <input type="text" placeholder="" value="@fld.response"/>
      <em>@fld.isRequired</em>
    </li>
   End If

  If fld.fieldTypeId = "para" Then
   @<li>
      <h4>@fld.title</h4>
      <em>@fld.description</em>
      @html.textarea(fld.response)
      <em>@fld.isRequired</em>
    </li>
   End If
Next
 <input type="submit" name="cmdSubmit" value="Submit" id="cmdSubmit"/>

End Using
```

**RespondController.vb**

```
<HttpPost>
<ActionName("Respond")>
Function Respond_post(viewModel As FormsRespondModel) As ActionResult

    Return View("Respond", viewModel)
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is my post action not populating my FormsRespondModel as it should?

Because your `<input>` and `<textarea>` fields don't have a `name` attribute. So absolutely nothing gets sent to the server when you submit the form.

You might consider using strongly typed helpers such as `Html.TextBoxFor` and `Html.TeaxAreaFor` in order to generate proper input fields. You might also take a look at the following blog post which explains how exactly your input fields should be named if you want model binding to work with collections: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

So for example to generate proper indexer names you might replace the `For Each` with a `For` loop:

```
@For i As Integer = 0 To Model.form.fields.Count -1 Step 1
    If Model.form.fields(i).fieldTypeId = "text" Then
    @<li>
        <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(x)x.form.fields(i).title)</h4>
        <em>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(x)x.form.fields(i).description)</em>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x)x.form.fields(i).response)
        <em>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(x)x.form.fields(i).isRequired)</em>
    </li>
    End If

    If Model.form.fields(i).fieldTypeId = "para" Then
    @<li>
        <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(x)x.form.fields(i).title)</h4>
        <em>@@Html.DisplayFor(Function(x)x.form.fields(i).description)</em>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(Function(x)x.form.fields(i).response)
        <em>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(x)x.form.fields(i).isRequired)</em>
    </li>
    End If
Next
```

Obviously in this example we only have input fields for the `response` property. So that will be the only thing being sent to the server when you submit the form and the only property on your view model that will be populated. If you want to get the other properties you might need to include them as hidden fields inside the form (using the `@Html.HiddenFor` helper). This being said, instead of generating a bunch of hidden fields in your form it might be much better to simply include as hidden field some unique identifier that will allow you to retrieve those properties from your backend in the POST action using this identifier.